# Structural Search IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, search, full-text-search, structural-search

I want to perform a structural search from IntelliJ IDEA.
My research is made up of two criteria:

1. Find all classes with custom **@CustomAnnotate** annotation

- This annotation is placed exclusively on Repository springs; the result of this research will exclusively cite Repositories

2. Find a text corresponding to the name of an `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` method; for example **findById**

- The result of this research will cite services calling for Repositories

I can't combine the two searches at the same time. i.e. the Repositories called to perform a findById (search 2) must have the annotation @CustomAnnotate (search 1).

I tried this: `$REPO$.$METHOD$($VARS$)`

With:

- `$REPO$` = a reference filter on the first reference search which has been recorded.
- `$METHOD$` = a type filter with "findById"
- `$VAR$` = [0, ∞]

The two criteria do not work together into my research, but they work independently.

What solution is possible? With a script?

Comment: You may use reference filter (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/search-templates.html#reference_filter). But ot's not possible to set annotation type.

Comment: Precisely, I am using a reference filter in $REPO$ but that does not work by coupling it with '$METHOD$' = a type filter with "findById". Any ideas ?